# My while loop is only iterating once python

Tags: loops, python-3.x, while-loop

I have seen questions like this before, but the problem is that they were in different languages. As far as I know, everything should work. However I am new to dealing with the time library and I think that I may have made a mistake there.

I am using a while loop that iterates ten times to simulate a rocket launch countdown.

Here is my code:

```
import time
x = 0
y = 10
print("Launch sequence initiated...")
time.sleep(3)
print(y)
while x > 10:
    y = y - 1
    time.sleep(1)
    print(y)
    x = x + 1
```

This is the only code (I don' t think that it requires much) that I have been running it as I was going through, but I cannot figure out what is wrong. The problem is that it only prints one value (10).

Comment: `x` starts off as `0` which means it's not greater than 10 so the while loop never enters...

Comment: You mean `x < 10`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You make `x = 0`, and we know `0 < 10`, so the loop won't even begin. Use `while x < 10:` instead:

```
import time
x = 0
y = 10
print("Launch sequence initiated...")
time.sleep(3)
print(y)
while x < 10:
    y = y - 1
    time.sleep(1)
    print(y)
    x = x + 1
```

BTW, if I were you, I would write something like this:

```
import time
print("Launch sequence initiated...")
time.sleep(3)
for x in range(10, -1, -1):
    print(x)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Since this is tagged Python 3.x - there is no `xrange` - you need `range` instead. Also - instead of doing maths inside the loop - adjust the range accordingly, eg: `range(10, -1, -1)`

Comment: @JonClements Edited.